# How can I remove all non-alphanumeric characters from a string, except for '#', with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I currently have this line `address = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', address).lstrip()` which will remove all special characters from my string `address`. How can I modify this line to keep `#`?

Comment: You mean not to remove `#`? `'[^A-Za-z0-9#]+'`

Comment: What is a "special character"?

Comment: `[]` is a list of things, if you start it with `^` it's things to exclude. So add what you need to the list

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, got the job done!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You should make your comment into an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: Worth noting that the \w metacharacter makes the code much simpler if you're willing to include '_' as an allowed character.

Comment: @James Thanks for the idea, however I need to remove underscores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to avoid removing the hash symbol, you need to add it into the [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
r'[^A-Za-z0-9#]+'
             ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP1yL8/1)